# Write PDF other than English language C#.Net or Angular

Tags: c#, angular, pdf, pdfpig

I have been trying to read a pdf file and convert it into another language selected by user via Google API. then I need to save the translated content to another file.
I have generated pdf file using c#.net and Angular but both are only supporting English language while most probably I have to translate file from English to other languages.

I have used [jsPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf) for angular and for C#.Net I have used [UglyToad.PdfPig](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfPig) but I am not able to save other languages

Comment: there are many libraries enabling to write pdf files and then downloads. these may be for node.js with ability to use with angular.

Answer (score 1):

did you try other PDF generation libraries?

i use [PDFFlow](https://go.pdfflow.io/pdflib-info) and I know it supports latin, cyrillic and asian languages

For example this simple code creates Chinese text :

```
{
    DocumentBuilder.New()
    .AddSection()                
        .AddParagraph("在这输 在入文这输 入文字")
        .SetFontEncodingName(EncodingNamesChineseSimplified.GBK_EUC_H)
        .SetFontName(FontNamesChineseSimplified.SimSun).ToDocument()
    .Build("Result.pdf");
}
```

the result pdf will be this:

[image]

try and tell me if you need further help or have any questions